# How can I tell my application that it shouldn't use an external Service Provider from a jar?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, jnlp, oracle-xdk

For some reason we need the xdb.jar from the Oracle XDK. This jar depends on the xmlparserv2.jar. The actual problem is that the xmlparserv2.jar comes with some provider-configuration files (META-INF/services). The jar has Services Providers for *javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory*, *javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory* and *javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory*. The implementations (from oracle.*) don't work together with some other parts of our software (they need the standard factories).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the services (META-INF/services). We ran our unit tests and everything worked. Even the parts of our software which are depending on xmlparserv2.jar/xdb.jar.

Answer (score 1):

You could use separate classloaders to isolate the jars from the rest of the application. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368483/running-class-in-separate-context) about covers it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove these classes from the xmlparserv2.jar

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible. The license of xmlparserv2.jar doesn't allow that. And the xmlparserv2.jar needs these classes.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6561417) - "JNLP classpath precedence 1.5 vs 1.6"

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve my problem. The xmlparserv2.jar is overwriting classes which are in the jre. I can't load the xmlparserv2.jar before the jre. (Can I?)

Comment: that's what the issue discusses - how and under what versions.

Comment: Okay, then I don't really understand the workaround. The xmlparserv2.jar includes following packages:
org.xml.sax.*
org.w3c.dom.*
oracle.xml.*
javax.xml.*
The problem proberbly came from the javax.xml.* package... But how can I tell the runtime not to use this part of the jar?