# XSSFWorkbook when written creates a corrupted .xlsx document in Spring Boot application using JDBC

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

For a project I need to create an `.xlsm` excel document automatically filling out a template file. Problem is, that the output is corrupted and cannot be read by Excel 365 nor by Apache POI.

I have distilled it down to the following minimal example, that can run in a `main` method. To be completely safe it is using the `.xlsx` format.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    XSSFWorkbook document = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = document.createSheet("Test");
    spreadsheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Testie test");

    // Output .xlsx file
    FileOutputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream("test_output.xlsx");
        document.write(stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
```

The created file `test_output.xlsx` cannot be opened by Excel 365 and has a size of only 4kb, while a manually created one would take up 9kb, so there must be something missing in the output that I have not specified?

I'm using Apache POI version 3.17 imported via Gradle using

```
compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17')
```

and also with Apache POI version 3.13 to have a version from before 2016. No luck in both cases.

When the main method is extended to also reopen the same file, that was just created, as shown below

```
    ...
    // Try to read it again
    try {
        document = new XSSFWorkbook("test_output.xlsx");
        System.out.println(document.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

then I end up in the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Can't read content types part !
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.openPackage(POIXMLDocument.java:91)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:340)
    ...
```

If on the other hand all `XSSF*` is replaced with `HSSF*` and the file type made into a `.xls` file, then the document outputted is fine, yet I need to create a working Excel 365 document, not an Excel 2003 one.

The following is `[Content_Types].xml` file in the manually made `.xlsx` document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
    <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/sharedStrings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
</Types>
```

While the following is `[Content_Types].xml` in the POI created file `.xlsx`

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default ="rels"/>
    <Default ="xml"/>
    <Override ="/docProps/app.xml"/>
    <Override ="/docProps/core.xml"/>
    <Override ="/xl/sharedStrings.xml"/>
    <Override ="/xl/styles.xml"/>
    <Override ="/xl/workbook.xml"/>
    <Override ="/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"/>
</Types>
```

Comment: Have you tried with earlier versions of library?

Comment: I have tried with 3.13 to get a version earlier than 2016 without any luck.

Comment: in fact I just try your example but it works, (I'm using Numbers in macOS)

Comment: What Java version are you using? Maybe any kind of [Java 10](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N102C9) problem?

Comment: @Azarea Hmm, I have the problem with both Office 365 and Libre Office. How big is the `test_output.xlsx` file you end up with? @Axel Richter We're using Java 8 (`sourceCompatibility = 1.8` in `build.gradle`), from which we cannot upgrade due to use of Spring Boot.

Comment: The lower file size is not any hint to failure here. Excel puts some unnecessary data in new files which POI doesn't.  A `*.xlsx` file can simply be unzipped. Do that and do comparing `/[Content_Types].xml` of  Excel generated and POI generated file. Because of error "Can't read content types part !".

Comment: @AxelRichter I have changed the try-with-resources as you suggested though there is no difference when I run it - it still creates the file without any complaints. I also updated the post with the `[Content_Types].xml` file. I can't seem to find a description of a barebones version, but without the `ContentType` value I would guess it is missing information?

Comment: Your `XML` in `[Content_Types].xml` definitely is wrong generated. There are only elements and some attribute content but none attribute names. But not reproducible, at least not for me. [ContentTypeManager](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/internal/ContentTypeManager.java?view=markup) uses `org.w3c.dom.Element` for generating XML elements. Maybe there are some jars in your class path which are badly owerwriting this?

Comment: @AxelRichter: what did you mean by "try-with-resources hides exception"?

Comment: @SteffanSølvsten: You wrote that you had tried with HSSF* and it works. What happens if you leave there XSSF on the right side, but properly use the interfaces on the left sides? I mean `Workbook document = new XSSFWorkbook(); Sheet spreadsheet = document.createSheet("Test");`

Comment: @AxelRichter: Oh, you mean if both the `write()` and `close()` methods throw an exception... OK.

Comment: The `[Content_Types].xml` after "removing dependencies to Spring Boot" looks correct now. And I suspect the `test_output.xlsx` also is no more corrupt now. I think you could get friends if you were able determining what exact dependency leads to the problem since there are others having problems using `apache poi` and `spring boot` together too. Me not because of not using `spring` at all.

Comment: Yup, I'm also right now onto writing it as the answer, it just took quite a bit of time time from updating the post to actually finding the root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the suggestions of @AxelRichter when all other dependencies are removed in `build.gradle` then [Content_Types].xml looks as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" Extension="rels"/>
    <Default ContentType="application/xml" Extension="xml"/>
    <Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml" PartName="/docProps/app.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml" PartName="/docProps/core.xml"/>
    <Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml" PartName="/xl/sharedStrings.xml"/>
    <Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml" PartName="/xl/styles.xml"/>
    <Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml" PartName="/xl/workbook.xml"/>
    <Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"/>
</Types>
```

And the above code runs without issues and the file can be opened in Office 365. The problem lies in the import of

```
compile('com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1')
```

Which creates a conflict in the classpath for the XML parser used by Apache POI, meaning either the Excel part needs to be done in another project with Gradle handling the dependency issues.

Comment: I am curious what exact class is in conflict there. But seems as if `ojdbc8.jar` is not public available, at least not without creating a Oracle account, what I don't want to do. Is there at least a class list of `ojdbc8.jar` public available somewhere?

Comment: @AxelRichter Maybe not exactly what you were asking for, but I've run a .bat script to extract all the content of the .jar file. https://pastebin.com/9Nzw2REH

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was after. But now I also cannot see where the conflict may be. There are involved classes having same name **Element** : `org.w3c.dom.Element` and `oracle.jdbc.pooling.LinkedListPool.Element` and `oracle.jdbc.pooling.PoolIteratorQueue.Element`. But they are fully qualified named and imported. So there should not be any conflict. Mysterious that.

Comment: @AxelRichter Maybe it is in the dependency of the _xmlparserv2.jar_ also downloaded together with _ojdbc8.jar_? It contains https://pastebin.com/LLEquXVf . It seems especially like there is some rerouting in the _META-INF/services_ folder.

Comment: Yes, seems `xmlparserv2.jar` is the problem here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412736/how-can-i-tell-my-application-that-it-shouldnt-use-an-external-service-provider. Maybe good to know for others who wants using `apache poi` and `Spring Boot` together.