# Isolating classpath between interdependent gradle modules

Tags: java, gradle, apache-poi, build.gradle, ojdbc

For a project we need to create an *.xlsm* excel document automatically filled with data entered into our application. All handling of the excel document is independent from the rest of the backend, so all of the direct handling of the Excel document is moved into its own module and the project hence has the following structure

```
+ BaseFolder
|- settings.gradle
|- build.gradle
|
+--+ backend
|  |- backend.gradle
|  |- src
|
+--+ excel
   |- excel.gradle
   |- src
```

In the *excel* module we chose to use Apache POI to fill out the `.xlsm` template file. Hence, the `excel.gradle` has the following dependency

```
compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17')
```

In the *backend* module we have to use Spring Tools to create the API and `ojdbc8` to communicate with an Oracle database for persistent storage of information. This data from the database needs to be written to the excel file, why in the dependencies of `backend.gradle` we have

```
compile project(':excel')
...
compile('com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1')
```

The *excel* project is used in the *backend* through a `TemplateBuilderAdapter`, which takes the database representation and calls the corresponding methods on `TemplateBuilder`.

When `.write(OutputStream stream)` is called on the Apache POI `XSSFWorkbook` from the `TemplateBuilder` inside the *excel* module the file created is as it should be. On the other hand, when `.write(OutputStream stream)` is called on `TemplateBuilderAdapter`, which merely passes it along to `TemplateBuilder`, the file is corrupted.

Given the deduction from [XSSFWorkbook when written creates a corrupted .xlsx document in Spring Boot application using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151125/) by compiling `ojdbc8` the class path ends up changing the XML parser used by Apache POI, which leads to the corrupted Excel files. We have tried to use a fat *.jar* file with all dependencies of the *excel* project, but that was without luck.

How can we use the *excel* project within the *backend* project without the classpath of everything used in the *excel* project being changed? And if we have to respecify the class path to clean up after the import of *ojdbc8* does anyone have any ideas as to where to what causes the conflict?

Comment: OSGi should take care of it for you, otherwise you're going to need to very careful things yourself with multiple classloaders...

Comment: @Gagravarr To use the OSGi gradle plugin, I would have to exactly pinpoint where exactly the conflict is created, such that I know what to _reset_ in the Manifest of the .jar, right?

Comment: What version of Gradle and Java are you using? I don't know for sure at this point, but Java 9 _might_ offer a solution with modules.

Comment: We are using Java 8 and Gradle 4.7