# One computer corrupts Excel files (that are created through my program through Apache POI), while other computers work fine

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, corruption

One aspect of my Java program deals with Excel file creation and manipulation (and simply opening the file) using Apache POI.

In the office in which the program is being used, one computer seems to corrupt any Excel file that it opens (but only Excel files created by my program, other Excel files work fine). However, other computers have no such issue.

When other computers attempt to open the Excel file, it is corrupted (I have tried everything to repair the files, but nothing works).

Furthermore, the program used to work fine on this computer as well. Suddenly, one day, it began corrupting all Excel files created through the system.

Error Popup: "We found a problem with some content in '6077 - model mixed - July 2018 - EHF 16837.xlsm'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

Comment: To answering this one would need the resulting Excel file from the one computer which creates a corrupt file to determine what went wrong. My suspicion is that the one computer is using other default libraries (to creating XML for example) than the computers where it runs properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151125/xssfworkbook-when-written-creates-a-corrupted-xlsx-document-in-spring-boot-appl for example.

Answer (score 0):

There a various reasons which could cause the behaviour. I'd suggest to analyse the excel file in more detail as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077245/812093 (e.g. find out the exact row number in the xml which is causing excel to fail). Maybe you can provide the information here then we can help you further